# Could not find default endpoint element that references contract

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm try to add web services.

This is my config file

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="Service1Soap" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
          receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" 
          maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" 
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
            maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:51272/Service1.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="Service1Soap" contract="ServiceReference1.Service1Soap" 
        name="Service1Soap"  />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

This is my controller where I call the web services.

```
 ServiceReference1.Service1Soap hs = new ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
 int aa = hs.getStockQty(66);
```

But there is error..

[image]

How can I solve it??
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your service configuration file as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the endpoint has more than one references , could you please delete the reference and add it again with a different name.

if not the solution is simple. Copy the endpoint definitions from the config file ) of the class library to the config file of the application.

also check the namespace of this contract "Service1Soap"